# sqlite3 permission denied android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to access the database of the application I'm developping directly on my Nexus, but I get a "permission denied" when I tried to execute the "sqlite3" command.
I also tried to start the adb in root mod, but again, permission denied on the device...
I guess I will have to do that with the emulator but I have a lot of data to load and it would have been 10 times faster with the phone on Wifi than the emulator...
Unless someone has any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical.

I worked around this annoyance by adding a feature to my app that backs up (copies) the DB to the SD card. `adb pull` works against any sdcard files.

EDIT: fixed "adb" misspelling (was "sdp".

Comment: What's sdp? Can you please post a link to sdp? Thank you.

Comment: @kilaka: Thanks - I fixed my typo - should read: "use the adb pull command" - Android Debug Bridge.

Comment: It didn't work because my phone is not rooted. It works with the emulator though.

Comment: Hey Brad, could you actually provide a snippet of code that demonstrates how to copy an existing database with mock names such as data/data/your.package.name/databases/your.db

Comment: Hi Michael - Check out copyfile function here: https://github.com/gtosoft/libvoyager/blob/master/src/com/gtosoft/libvoyager/db/DashDB.java

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with this for a while, so here's my solution, which works on an unrooted device:

```
#!/bin/sh

# fill these values in
PACKAGE=com.example.android
DB=something.db 

# copy db to sdcard using package permission (using cat because no cp    command)
adb shell "run-as $PACKAGE cat /data/data/$PACKAGE/databases/$DB >   /sdcard/$DB"

# pull file from sd card
adb pull /sdcard/$DB

# do something with it (need to install sqlitebrowser obviously)
sqlitebrowser $DB
```

Comment: Thank you @eggbert. Its very helpfull and worked for me (using Ubuntu 10.04) and tried with debugable app on unrooted device.

Comment: This worked, but in my phone (HTC Desire), the database file didn't have a `.db` extension at the end.

Answer (score 4):

The files are read protected, you need to root your phone or use the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I pulled sqlite3 from emulator and pushed in on my device and couldn't run it - permission denied.

Apparently sqlite3 binary didn't have execute permission (-rw-rw-rw-) so chmod +x sqlite3 solved the issue.