# Why does the SQLite 3 command using the Android ADB shell return "permission denied"?

Tags: android, shell, permissions, adb, nexus-one

Specifically, I was trying to use the `sqlite3` command with the ADB shell to run some queries on the database of the Android application I'm building.

I kept getting "sqlite3: permission denied". I'm developing on a Nexus One that I purchased from Google. Does my phone need to be rooted or something?

```
$ sqlite3 /data/data/com.moodme.android/databases/moodme.db
sqlite3 /data/data/com.moodme.android/databases/moodme.db
sqlite3: permission denied
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013231/sqlite3-permission-denied-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files are read protected. You need to root your phone or use the emulator.

Comment: Thanks.  Successfully rooted my nexus one.  Now getting a different error.  Opening new question for that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645319/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite3-not-found-error-on-a-rooted-nexus-one-when-i-try-to-ope

Comment: seems like being able to look at database content is a part of software development. Why need to root the phone to do that?

Comment: It's a protection mechanism. It helps keep developers from snooping at the details of other apps on their phone. Legitimate developers are expected to purchase a Dev phone from Google that is already unlocked, so you can use SQLite3 in this way, as well as explore the `/data` directory structure.