# How can I install sqlite3 on rooted NexusOne runs Gingerbread

Tags: android

I am rooted my nexus one which runs Gingerbread. But like the following post, I can't find sqlite3 and would like to install sqlite3 on Nexus One:

[Why do I get a "sqlite3: not found" error on a rooted Nexus One when I try to open a database using the adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645319/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite3-not-found-error-on-a-rooted-nexus-one-when-i-try-to-ope)

I did in 1 shell

```
$ adb shell
$ su
# mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

and in another shell, I did

```
$ cd ~/NexusOne/SuperOneClickv1.7-ShortFuse
$ adb push sqlite3 /system/bin
failed to copy 'sqlite3' to '/system/bin/sqlite3': Permission denied
```

I have tried the answer. But I get this. I clearly have 'sqlite3' but it does not let me move to /usr/bin.

```
# mv sqlite3 /usr/bin
failed on 'sqlite3' - No such file or directory
# pwd
/mnt/sdcard
# ls sqlite3
sqlite3
# mv sqlite3 /usr/bin
failed on 'sqlite3' - No such file or directory
# ls -l sqlite3
----rwxr-x system   sdcard_rw    24120 2010-10-16 22:04 sqlite3
```

How can I create '/usr/bin' on my Nexus one? and have /usr/bin on my shell path?

Answer (score 8):

Use the following commands sequence. 
Before entering "su" command unlock your device to see dialog for granting access

```
$ adb push sqlite3 /sdcard/
$ adb shell
$ su
# mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
# dd if=/sdcard/sqlite3 of=/system/bin/sqlite3
# chmod 4755 /system/bin/sqlite3
# mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

Comment: On my Xiaomi MI3 with rooted MIUI, these instructions did not work. I finally needed to use [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273269/nexus-5-sqlite3-enable-load-extension-referenced-by-sqlite3) . FYI for any other users MIUI users coming here.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cd ~/NexusOne/SuperOneClickv1.7-ShortFuse
$ adb push sqlite3 /sdcard/
$ adb shell
$ su
# cp /sdcard/sqlite3 /usr/bin
```