# Sqlite3 not installed. How the android read messages from mmssms.db

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

Running an emulator when i connect using Android Debug Bridge i was able to run standard T-SQL query like

```
C:\program files\android\android-sdk\platform-tools adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db "Select * FROM sms;
```

but when i connected my rooted android phone using the `adb` it gave me a message like

> Select not found

then i [**installed sqlite**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7076409/335105) on the phone and it worked

**Question:**

if sqlite is not installed on the phone how the sms messages are read from `mmssms.db` by the phone OS (android)? why i was not able to run a Select prior to the installation of sqlite3 on the android phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the command-line tools aren't installed, doesn't mean there's no code on the device that can access the database -- applications will use a library, rather than calling the `sqlite3` executable.

Comment: and the sqlite3 exe uses that libraries too or it has its own way of working things out? i feel like i'm lost and talking gibberish `:|` can i get access to system libraries? ... tnx for clearing things up

Comment: Depends on the executable -- I think that if you're coping files to the device manually, they are likely to be statically linked -> not using system libraries.  You get access to the system libraries by writing Android applications :).