# Nexus 5 "sqlite3_enable_load_extension" referenced by "sqlite3"

Tags: android, sqlite

Background Information:

1. Nexus 5
2. Have rooted permission on device
3. pull sqlite3 from my emulator
      ADB pull /system/bin/sqlite3
4. push this sqlite3 onto my device
      ADB push sqlite3 /sdcard/
5. adb shell
6. su
7. move sqlite3 into /system/xbin/ directory

   # mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

   # dd if=/sdcard/sqlite3 of=/system/xbin/sqlite3

   # chmod 777 /system/xbin/sqlite3

   # mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

Keep getting error when I try to use sqlite3.  For example:

# sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db

The error I got is:

CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: cannot locate symbol "sqlite3_enable_load_extension" referenced by "sqlite3"...

Does anyone know how to get sqlite3 running successfully on Nexus 5 device ?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem. I found this Version working for Jelly Bean http://bit.ly/sqlite3-for-jb on my N5 4.4.2.

```
adb push sqlite3-for-jb /sdcard/sqlite3
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
cp /sdcard/sqlite3 /system/xbin/sqlite3
chmod 755 /system/xbin/sqlite3
mount -o remount,ro /system
```

Comment: This worked on my rooted Xiaomi MI3 with rooted MIUI. I think getting the right binary is the key. The Sqlite Installed for Root did not work on my phone & kept giving 'Unable to remount /system' message.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use "SQlite Installer For Root" from the play shop.