# Manually Input of data into sqlite table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How I can Manually Insert data into sqlite database table.
Manually mean insertion of data through Laptop like we are doing in MS access table etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a specific code issue.

Comment: I use the SQLiteManager plugin for FireFox. Next question follows: `How do I provide a prepopulated database to my app?`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930406/insert-values-into-sqlite-database-manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try to look for GUI clients for SQLite**

SQLite Studio http://sqlitestudio.pl/

SQLite Browser http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ (http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

SQLite Admin http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/

SQLite Spy http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index

SQLite Expert http://www.sqliteexpert.com/features.html

**Commercial Tools like**

Navicat http://www.navicat.com/download/navicat-for-sqlite

Maestro https://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/maestro/

**Otherwise**

Google chrome plugins

Firefox Addons

Comment: I have added SQLite Spy which is free

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can insert the data in SQLite database manually by following steps.

Steps to follow:

```
1) Go to your sdk-tool directory . (Example - E:\android-sdk-windows\tools>)
2) Type adb shell and press enter
3) cd data
4) cd data
5) cd your package name
6) cd databases
```

Once you reach here then do these steps to create database and create tables then insert data into it

```
sqlite3 your_database_name.db;
SQLite version 3.7.7 2011-06-25 16:35:41
```

Enter ".help" for instructions Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE province_table (pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, pname TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO province_table (pname) values ('Quebec');
sqlite> ...
sqlite> .q
```

.q for quiet from SQLlite and now you have database your_database_name.db.

But here in your case if you want to create the database for all mobile such like that once your application run the start database manipulation then you must to do it programmatically.

Comment: The questions asked is, to edit, delete, insert like a GUI Excel sheet or MS ACCESS

Comment: where can i find  sdk-tool directory?

Comment: look into the directory where you have installed android studio

Comment: In my case it is 'C:\Android\sdk\tools'  and most probably in your case it'll be same