# Where can I get a sqlite binary for use in adb shell?

Tags: android, sqlite

Does there exists a sqlite binary for android adb shell for analyzing and fixing application sqlite database?

Comment: This may be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485890/how-to-install-or-get-access-to-sqlite3-from-adb-shell. Personally I drop copies of the database into SQLite manager (Browser extension) or even modify and then copy into device.

Comment: This may also be of use https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/where-can-i-obtain-an-sqlite-3-command-line-binary-for-android

Answer (score 0):

You can always launch an emulator, then pull out the sqlite binary (you have a root shell so it won't be a problem)  (for example adb pull /system/bin/sqlite). 
Now you can push it into your device, add execute permission and enjoy it