# How to copy images to Android emulator's sd card from hard disk?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have to implement an Android 2.2 application which should be able to upload images selected from it's gallery, But I have no device with Android 2.2 so I have to test this on emulator, but I don't know how to copy images to emulator's sd card from my computer's hard disk. There are lot of similar type posts I found and none of them worked for me. So I hope your help

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using  DDMS tool (under Eclipse or not), you can just drag and drop your image to the selected folder. SDCard folder is under mnt folder.

[image]

**Edited**

DDMS can be found under ...\android-sdk\tools.
In Eclipse, it is a perspective you can add by clicking on *Window > Open Perspective > Other... > DDMS*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I use Eclipse. How to add DDMS tool for Eclipse?

Comment: is it possible to do this through command line, using `adb shell` ?

Comment: @user13267 See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650407/how-to-copy-selected-files-from-android-with-adb-pull

Answer (score 0):

adb push foo.jpg /sdcard/foo.jpg

Follow the documentation here : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#copyfiles