# How to use adb pull command?

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator, android-ndk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy selected files from Android with adb pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650407/how-to-copy-selected-files-from-android-with-adb-pull)

I am using adb pull command like this:

```
adb pull /sdcard/*.trace C:/
```

but i show me remote object '/sdcard/*.trace' does not exit i check trace files are in the sdcard.Now how to pull these files from sdcard.Can you help me How to fix?

Comment: Don't [repost questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994599/how-to-pull-trace-file-in-android), even if you delete the original.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think adb pull handles wildcards for multiple files. I ran into the same problem and did this by moving the files to a folder and then pulling the folder.

I found a link doing the same thing. Try following these steps.

[How to copy selected files from Android with adb pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650407/how-to-copy-selected-files-from-android-with-adb-pull)

Comment: Thanks,Now I want to traceview it show me trace file 'MyGraph.trace' not found :(