# View sqlite database on android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am using android studio to develop my first android app.

I am plugging in my phone, and testing my app on there to test changes as I go.

I am using a sqlite database. How do I view this database, the tables, and the contents (rows) of those tables?

Upon Google searching I found that this can be done when you root your phone. But surely you dont have to root your phone to view your databases when your developing an app?

Update:

People are using terminology assuming knowledge. If you want me to copy a database, explain how, if you want me to use adb, explain what it is. Otherwise it means not much to me. Thanks

Comment: copy your database from internal to external storage so that you can access it

Comment: use emulator  and  you can find your database at  /data/data/{yourapp}

Comment: @kamran so once emulator is running, how do i find my database?

Comment: open the DDMS perspective --> file explorer --then data folder --->data--yourapp

Comment: The BEST solution was @Bob's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194576/how-do-i-view-the-sqlite-database-on-an-android-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the sqlite database named as XYZ.db from your simulator or device using `adb shell` command or GUI interface provided by the AndroidStudio. Then Open it using The [Sqlite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). It's a killer app for sqlite browsing.

As android is shipped with the sqlite3, you could use command line to view the data base saved inside the device / emulator. Command reference is Listed [Sqlite3 android command](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sqlite3.html)

If you feel lazy enough to discover how to pull files from emulator / device using `adb pull`, following answer may help you.
[how to pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650407/how-to-copy-selected-files-from-android-with-adb-pull)

Answer (score 0):

At least in my case I needed to root my device. After that I installed SQLiteEditor. With this app you can modify and view your database. Or if you don't want to install a new app you can use a root explorer and enter directly into your installed app in the DB. Is inside /data/data/{yourapp}.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your database to your system

1. Using copy or paste Or
2. Using adb pull command

Then Googled for **sqlitestudio-2.1.4**, download and run , browse your database ,,then you can see your database rows, column, value etc.