# Retrieve database or any other file from the Internal Storage using run-as

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, adb, internal-storage

On a non-rooted android device, I can navigate to the data folder containing the database using the `run-as` command with my package name. Most files types I am content with just viewing, but with the database I would like to pull if from the android device.

Is there a `download` `copy` or `move` command from this part of adb shell? I would like to download the database file and view its content using a database browser.

One answer here involves turning entire application package into a compressed archive, but there is no further answer on how to extract that archive once this is done and moved to the machine, leaving me very sidetracked when there might be a more direct solution to begin with

Comment: Try adb pull

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650407/how-to-copy-selected-files-from-android-with-adb-pull

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/ Pull database without rooting device

Answer (score 253, accepted):

By design `user` build of Android (that's what you have on your phone until you unlock the *bootloader* and flash the phone with `userdebug` or `eng` software) restricts access to the *Internal Storage* - every app can only access its own files. Fortunately for software developers not willing to *root* their phones Google provides a way to access the *Internal Storage* of *debuggable* versions of their packages using `run-as` command.

To download the `/data/data/debuggable.app.package.name/databases/file` from an Android 5.1+ device run the following command:

```
adb exec-out run-as debuggable.app.package.name cat databases/file > file
```

To download multiple files in a folder under the `/data/data/debuggable.app.package.name/` at once - use `tar`:

```
adb exec-out run-as debuggable.app.package.name tar c databases/ > databases.tar
adb exec-out run-as debuggable.app.package.name tar c shared_prefs/ > shared_prefs.tar
```

Comment: Or, just use `run-as` to copy the file to a spot on external storage, and pull the database file from there, rather than messing around with file permissions.

Comment: The run-as has no permission to write to the sdcard - there is something new added with the latest update... :(

Comment: When I run adb shell "run-as package.name chmod 666 /data/data/package.name/databases/file" adb ends me error -->run-as: exec failed for chmod666 Error:Permission denied .
I'm in Nexus 7 without root

Comment: Write access to external sd card is no longer possible with adb.

Comment: Did you check if this depends on the permissions of the app you run as?

Comment: When transferring my database using "adb exec-out run-as package.name cat databases/file > file", I'm getting extra line-breaks (CR LF), making the file unreadable by sqliteman. Looks like the file is being copied as text rather than binary. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @GyumFox, double check Android version of your device. The whole purpose of `adb exec-out` is to run a `shell` command without `tty` so it would not mangle the output.

Comment: in case anyone else is confused about the "exec out" command: exec out makes the adb command running on your computer return whatever it is that the shell on Android "returns". That means that the pipe ( "> file" ) happens on your computer, not the Android device. "file" will then be a file in the current dir from where you ran the adb command on your computer.

Comment: So this *seems* to work for me, but the file that I get, is a few hundred bytes different in size. This is if I cat the output to my local shell. If I redirect the output of cat to a file on the device (e.g. "/sdcard/out.db", I get just a 0-byte-sized file.

Comment: @AlexP., I think the issue is with the cat command, which copies the content of the file as text, rather than binary

Comment: The only solution that worked for me. I mean the one for Android 5.0+

Comment: This doesn't work for me because the cmd output is: File is in use by a different process. Is there a way around this? I'm running a service that constantly writes to the DB. But even if I deactivate the app, it does not work. Any help?

Comment: @Spurious You might want to try going to Developer Options (on the phone) then Running Services, find your app/service and kill it from there.

Comment: @AlexP. The 5.0+ worked like a charm for me, but what if we have reverse situation and want to put db from our pc to application? I tried: adb exec-in run-as my.application cat mydbname.db > databases/intouchDatabase with no luck it just says 'The system cannot find the path specified.' I coulnd't find much about exec-in tbh, also i suspect it cannot find the mydbname.db location.

Comment: @AlexP. I've already seen that post, it's not exactly reverse as you just move files from sdcard not the pc, when I'm trying following: _adb shell run-as my.application cp mydbname.db databases/mydb_ I am getting following response: _cp mydbname.db: No such file or directory_

Comment: @AlexP. I tried moving the db to sdcard with adb push mydbname.db /sdcard/mydbname.db and then using cp and now I am getting /sdcard/mydbname.db: Permission denied. I checked the permissions on sdcard and its -rwxrwx--- root (my phone is not rooted). I remember when I had older phone android 4.2.2 there were absolutely no problems with accessing stuff on sdcard. But when _adb pull /sdcard/mydbname mydbname_ it works without any problems.

Comment: I am having trouble with the execution of the exec-out command on an Samsung device running 6.0. I get a plain text document file which a can't view with sqlitebrowser for example. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you are finding that you are getting back a blank or nearly blank file, you may find that the file is simply an error from the console that has been redirected to this file that you have created. A frequent issue here is that you are trying to copy a DB from the Release variant of your app. **You can only copy DBs from the Debug variant of your app**. If this happens, just install the debug variant and try the command again. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: In my case `Marshamallow` it does not show any error, but file not found anywhere in internal sd card. where does it pull the file. Please help me out !!!

Comment: Not work for Windows 10 (64 bit), Android 6.0. File db pull from device but it's empty.

Comment: Note run-as is broken on recent Samsung phones.  Works great on pixel, LG, HTC, Sony, etc

Comment: Note that `adb exec-out` seems to capture stderr on the device and prints it to *stdout* locally.  That means that if `tar` prints error messages (e.g. if you give it an absolute path), they'll end up in the generated `.tar` file and make it malformed.

Answer (score 75):

The accepted answer doesn't work anymore for me (blocked by Android?)

So instead I did this:

```
> adb shell
shell $ run-as com.example.package
shell $ chmod 666 databases/file
shell $ exit                                               ## exit out of 'run-as'
shell $ cp /data/data/package.name/databases/file /sdcard/
shell $ run-as com.example.package
shell $ chmod 600 databases/file
> adb pull /sdcard/file .
```

Comment: This should be the new correct answer OR @Alex P. you should add this answer for newer Android versions.
Also in my case I had to use 777 and apply it to the database-directory first/as-well before I could access the db file.

Comment: My device is rooted, but I found I still need to run `su` to get the `run-as` command working.

Comment: What if you don't have SD card?

Comment: if you don't have an SD card, there's still a "sdcard" directory anyways.

Comment: This is the new answer for 5.0+ Android Devices. If I could I would upvote this answer 5 times.

Comment: Another solution that helps even for non-debuggable applications is described there: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/50411/96640.

Comment: Can I create a db file outside a device, manually create 'databases' directory inside the device, and copy the db file into the directory?

Comment: you can, just use `run-as <package>` when you need to act in behalf of the app

Comment: Great!. it worked for me too. Can we make a batch/shell file? just passing db file name as param and we have the db file.

Comment: By following these step i got the db file. But after that  my app is getting crashed after some time in same device only. App is working perfectly in other devices.

Answer (score 32):

If anyone looking for pulling database from **debug application** may use the procedure below:

> 1. search and open device file explorer

[image: search and open device file explorer]

> 2. Select your handset and then browse to `data/data` directory

[image: go to data/data directory]

> 3. Now find your application package and go to databases folder. You can see the databases there and upon right click, you will get option
>      to save this in your drive.

[image]

Comment: Wow, so much easier and safer compared to using adb-shell

Comment: In Android Studio 4.1.3 View->Tool Windows->Device File Explorer

Comment: Easiest way! Thank you!

Comment: Best easiest working way !

Comment: Hi, this is nice way to get a file from device. But can I do this without opening or creating a project?

Comment: You can do it with any debug application.

Answer (score 9):

I've published a simple shell script for dumping databases:

> https://github.com/Pixplicity/humpty-dumpty-android

It performs two distinct methods described here:

1. First, it tries to make the file accessible for other users, and attempting to pull it from the device.
2. If that fails, it streams the contents of the file over the terminal to the local machine. It performs an additional trick to remove `\r` characters that some devices output to the shell.

From here you can use a variety of CLI or GUI SQLite applications, such as `sqlite3` or `sqlitebrowser`, to browse the contents of the database.

Comment: This script is for debuggable applications, how about if app is not debuggable?

Comment: Your only options are likely to use backup tools, if the app in question exposes that data as part of a backup. Beyond that, I'm afraid it would require elevated permissions.

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't get anything else to work for me but this:

```
adb shell
run-as package.name
cat /databases/databaseFileName.db > /sdcard/copiedDatabaseFileName.db
exit
exit
adb pull /sdcard/copiedDatabaseFileName.db /file/location/on/computer/
```

The first exit is to exit out of the run-as, the second exit is to exit out of adb shell to do the pull.

Answer (score 5):

For app's debug version, it's very convenient to use command `adb exec-out run-as xxx.yyy.zzz cat somefile > somefile` to extract a single file. But you have to do multiple times for multiple files. Here is a simple script I use to extract the directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
P=
F=
D=

function usage()
{
    echo "$(basename $0) [-f file] [-d directory] -p package"
    exit 1
}

while getopts ":p:f:d:" opt
do
    case $opt in
        p)
            P=$OPTARG
            echo package is $OPTARG
            ;;
        f)
            F=$OPTARG
            echo file is $OPTARG
            ;;
        d)
            D=$OPTARG
            echo directory is $OPTARG
            ;;
        \?)
            echo Unknown option -$OPTARG
            usage
            ;;
        \:)
            echo Required argument not found -$OPTARG
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done

[ x$P == x ] && {
    echo "package can not be empty"
    usage
    exit 1
}

[[ x$F == x  &&  x$D == x ]] && {
    echo "file or directory can not be empty"
    usage
    exit 1
}

function file_type()
{
    # use printf to avoid carriage return
    __t=$(adb shell run-as $P "sh -c \"[ -f $1 ] && printf f || printf d\"")
    echo $__t
}

function list_and_pull()
{
    t=$(file_type $1)
    if [ $t == d ]; then
        for f in $(adb shell run-as $P ls $1)
        do
            # the carriage return output from adb shell should
            # be removed
            mkdir -p $(echo -e $1 |sed $'s/\r//')
            list_and_pull $(echo -e $1/$f |sed $'s/\r//')
        done
    else
        echo pull file $1
        [ ! -e $(dirname $1) ] && mkdir -p $(dirname $1)
        $(adb exec-out run-as $P cat $1 > $1)
    fi
}

[ ! -z $D ] && list_and_pull $D
[ ! -z $F ] && list_and_pull $F
```

Hope it would be helpful. This script is also available at [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/WanghongLin/9a239c20f6d91584a6173b205baf92e1/raw/1ab485ecf2493cfc1249b1085b6aa285fe81400d/exec_out.sh).

Typical usage is

```
$ ./exec_out.sh -p com.example.myapplication -d databases
```

then it will extract all files under your apps databases directory, which is `/data/data/com.example.myapplication/databases`, into current directory.

Comment: even for multiple files it is still just a single command. check the update https://stackoverflow.com/a/18472135/1778421 if you would prefer you could also add another pipe on the host side to unpack the files

Answer (score 3):

Much much simpler approach to download the file onto your local computer:

In your PC shell run:

```
adb -d shell 'run-as <package_name> cat /data/data/<package_name>/databases/<db_name>' > <local_file_name>
```

Comment: Pretty close but this pulls out a malformed db for me.

Comment: I had to skip the `-d` in my case, otherwise this is the way I always look for (i.e. google for) when trying to pull a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
#export for adb
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/userMe/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/userMe/Library/Android/sdk/tools

adb -d shell 'run-as com.android.app  cp /data/data/com.android.app/files/db.realm /sdcard'
adb pull sdcard/db.realm /Users/userMe/Desktop/db
```

You can use this script for get Realm database.

Answer (score 1):

The database file is **emtpy** when using `adb run-as`. This can be resolved by calling close() on the RoomDatabase instance. Call close() to let SQLite write its journal to disk.
I've created this button that closes the database connection on request:

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/KZYnGwVh8ICN73jXod)

[Here is how to call close](https://eimertvink.nl/2019/05/08/android-adb-retrieve-database-using-run-as.html) on the RoomDatabase instance.

Comment: I was facing the issue : DB copied but not with the latest data. Closing the db connection before db file copy fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to pull app db(installed in debug mode) from device

Close DB connection if opened

Open cmd (command prompt) (Change dir to your adb path)

> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

(list the app files)

> adb -d shell "run-as com.xyz.name ls
> /data/data/com.xyz.name/files/"

(copy required file to sdcard)

> adb -d shell "run-as com.xyz.name cp
> /data/data/com.xyz.name/files/abc.db /sdcard/abc.db"

(copy from sdcard to machine adb folder)

> adb pull /sdcard/abc.db

Open DB connection

Destination file path in my case C:\Users{userName}\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
Or Device storage

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works on a device running Android 5.1. The following example is for Windows.

You need [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) (or sed.exe on windows, e.g. from cygwin.) ( On Unix, it'll just be there ;) ). To remove bad '\r' characters, at least on windows.

Now just run the following command:

```
adb exec-out "run-as com.yourcompany.yourapp /data/data/com.yourcompany.yourapp/databases/YourDatabaseName" | c:\cygwin\bin\sed.exe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/'>YourDatabaseName.db
```

The sed command strips out trailing /r characters.

Of course you should replace "com.yourcompany.yourapp" with the package name of the app and "YourDatabaseName" with the name of the database in the app.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for another answer that can be used to retrieve `Database` as well as `Shared Preferences` then follow this step:

In your `build.gradle` file of your app add line

> debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0'

now when you run your app in `non-release` mode then your app will automatically open 8080 port from your device `IP address` make sure your device is connected via `wifi` and your `laptop` is sharing the same network. Now simply visit the url

> http://your_mobile_device_ip:8080/

to watch all data of database along with shared preferences.