# Database is created for emulator but not for android device

Tags: android, database, emulation, device, sqliteopenhelper

I am making an android app in which database is created with sqlite open helper. when I installed my app in emulator it works fine but when I did the same thing to test in my phone I don't see any database created in DDMS file explorer view data/data. It is coming out to be empty. Please help me out with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Just check if you can query or the database. Insert and then fetch something to be sure. DDMS may be wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471780/android-adb-retrieve-database-using-run-as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root the android device

or

write a code for coping db file to sdcard

Code for coping database from /data/data directory to sdcard

```
public void copyDBToSDCard() {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//"+getPackageName()+"//databases//"+DB_NAME+"";
            String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }

        }
        Toast.makeText(print.this, 
                   "Database Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(print.this, 
                   "Error="+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("FO","exception="+e);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Joby. Yes this was the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can see on **DDMS** private files of application (from **data/data** directory) on **emulator** but it is not possible to see in **device without root**. But it is not means that database doesn't not exist. If you want to get db from real device, you have to root it or write some code in your app which copies db file on sdcard.

Comment: Thanks. That might be the reason. But I recently updated my phone to Lollipop. Before that I was able to see the database after pulling from my device in my system. Previously also it was not rooted. Does rooting harm my device? Then I would like to give it a try.

Comment: It is depend from device. You can lose guarantee. And if you have Samsung device with KNOX you will burn the bit. Basically the rooting of device is not good practice. If you don't have to don't do this.

Comment: So you can accept my solution? If it is help you of course.

Comment: Yes the database was created. I returned the getCount() method from the cursor which is getting updated everytime. That means my code is working perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help @KonradKrakowiak.

Comment: @RiddhiWala Did you try my solution? If it was helpful for you please accept it :)