# Android check db file with "run -as" on windows

Tags: android, windows, adb

Hi I am trying to access my android application db file which is non-rooted device. I tried "run -as" command on windows but it not working. It is giving me following error :

```
/system/bin/sh: run: not found
```

Am I doing any thing wrong? Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: I use a simpler way: **1** - Copy the db on the pc. **2** - Open it in FireFox SQLite Manager plugin.

Comment: @DerGol...lum thank you for quick help. I want that db file first then I can copy and open it. So I am trying to copy that file first

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/18472135/1778421

Comment: the command is not `run -as` but `run-as`. voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 0):

run-as command was available on Android Device till 2.3  Gingerbread OS. Beyond that this script was no longer available. Either root your device to read them or write a method to copy the database file to /sdcard path or /data/local/tmp and use LauncherAcitivity's oncreate to call that method to make it available on sdcard or tmp path.

EDIT:

run-as is a spaceless keyword. In your question, it seemed to have a space between run and hyphen. Double check it.

Comment: Edited the answer. Seems like you have a space in the script caller. I just checked in 4.3 jelly bean and found run-as script presence.

Comment: May be OS 5+ does not have them. Long back, I heard it was a deprecated script but not sure.

Comment: yeah I also heard that. But is there any alternative way to do that?

Comment: I guess you have no option if you device is not rooted and cannot introduce debug method as I wrote in answer.