# android adb shell script - how to pull all sharedpreferences

Tags: android, shell, adb

I need to run a script in debug mode that will pull all sharedpreferences into a folder.  From my research i can only pull from debug builds.  I tried from a non-rooted phone to get the sharedpreferences like this:

```
$adb shell
$adb run-as mypackagename
```

then i was able to traverse to /data/data/mypackagename/shared_prefs

but i'd like to be able to put this in a script.  I can only call adb pull from outside adb shell.  **how can i get the shared_prefs entire folder pulled out of a normal non-rooted device on a debug application ? there must be a way because how is facebook  setho doing it** ?

This question is about retrieving sharedPreferences not a database retrieval.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android adb, retrieve database using run-as](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471780/android-adb-retrieve-database-using-run-as)

Comment: thats about database, this is sharedpreference.  Although slightly similar my question speaks specifically about shared preference retrieval. Some can be in private mode etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created the following shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

pname=$1

if [ -z "${pname}" ]; then
    echo "Please enter a package name"
    exit 1
fi

adb shell "run-as $pname chmod 776 shared_prefs"
adb pull /data/data/$pname/shared_prefs ./${pname}_shared_prefs
adb shell "run-as $pname chmod 771 shared_prefs"
```

name it pullsharedprefs.sh (or whatever you want) and from terminal run the command:

```
chmod +x pullsharedprefs.sh
./pullsharedprefs.sh some.package.name
```

shared_prefs will be pulled to the current working directory and named {package-name}_shared_prefs

---

Tested using genymotion (Android 5.1.1)

Comment: When I run this against my device (running Nougat), I see the following error when trying to `pull`: `adb: error: remote object '/data/data/<redacted>/shared_prefs' does not exist` even though I can see and inspect the shared preferences directory if I manually use the device shell. Any ideas why that might be?