# Android Adb, retrieve database using run-as but with file name that has space

Tags: android, shell, android-sqlite, adb

I want to retreive android database using run-as like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471780/android-adb-retrieve-database-using-run-as), like this way :

```
adb shell
shell $ run-as com.example.package
shell $ chmod 666 databases/file
shell $ exit                                               ## exit out of 'run-as'
shell $ cp /data/data/package.name/databases/file /sdcard/
shell $ run-as com.example.package
shell $ chmod 600 databases/file
adb pull /sdcard/file
```

but my database file has space like "my db", what kind of punctuation that I must used ?

/ or " " or ' ' or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the quotation mark `"`
`chmod 666 databases/"my db"`