# android access log file from pc

Tags: java, android, java.util.logging

My 6.0.1 app behaves strangely on 2013 nexus (which is *not* rooted) when power cycles, so I am attempting to write a log file to the internal storage. I have socket logging over the WiFi working to the PC, but the problem occurs when the power is recycled, and my app starts when it receives a boot complete, so I thought I would write a log file, so I am trying:

```
    String filename="tablet.log";
    File logFile = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
    p("log file: "+logFile);
    try {
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(logFile);
        outputStream.write("foo\n".getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        p("wrote to log file: ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(logFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String string=bufferedReader.readLine();
        inputStream.close();
        p("read from log file: "+string);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Logger global=Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
    LoggingHandler.init();
    LoggingHandler.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
    try {
        p("log file get name: "+logFile.getPath());
        Handler handler=new FileHandler(logFile.getPath());
        handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        l.addHandler(handler);
        l.warning("added file handler: "+handler);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        l.warning("file handler caught: "+e);
    }
```

I *seem* to be writing the file and the file handler seems to be added, but I can not see the file when I use adb:

```
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\Cb7>adb -s 0a9196e8 shell ls /data/user/0/com.tayek.tablet.gui.android.cb7
```

gets: opendir failed, Permission denied

Is there any way to get the file to the PC?

thanks

edit: jared's suggestion works: adb shell run-as com.tayek.tablet.gui.android.cb7 ls files - will show me the files!

also, adb exec-out run-as package.name cat files/file > file gets the file to the PC.

looks like one needs: adb -s %device% shell run-as %package% ls -l /data/data/%package%/files

Comment: Have you tried writing your log to `Environment.getDataDirectory()` as opposed to the application data path (getFilesDir) ?

Comment: no, will try now. thanks

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/tablet.log: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied). i do have:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: also: >adb -s 0a9196e8 shell ls /data
opendir failed, Permission denied

Comment: I will write logs to the external storage instead of internal storage, then adb pull will help me solve the problem.

Comment: not sure i have or will have any external storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files in `/data` are not readable by the `shell` user. You need to use the `run-as` command, which will work as long as the debug build is installed.

---

You can check if the file exists:

```
adb shell run-as com.tayek.tablet.gui.android.cb7 ls files
```

---

To copy the file to your PC, you will need to copy the log file to your SD card and then use `adb pull` to retrieve the file. On Android 5.0+ you could simply do:

```
adb shell exec-out run-as package.name cat files/tablet.log > tablet.log
```

This should work on previous (and current) Android versions:

```
> adb shell
$ run-as package.name
$ cp files/tablet.log $EXTERNAL_STORAGE/tablet.log
$ exit
> adb pull /sdcard/tablet.log
```

Obviously, replace `package.name` with your package name (`com.tayek.tablet.gui.android.cb7`).

---

See: [android adb, retrieve database using run-as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471780/android-adb-retrieve-database-using-run-as)

Comment: Jared `exec-out` doesnt seem to work for me. I am getting `/system/bin/sh: exec-out: not found` - it seems to work fine without `exec-out`