# Finding database file

Tags: android, database, sqlite, path-finding

Hello I've got problem that i cannot find my database file. I haven't got data/data folder. I'm using my phone as emulator. And I can't really find my database. have you got any idea please how to find it? I would be really glad for any response.

Comment: i haven't seen it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18471780/115145

Comment: i've already tried adb but i can not find package folder. A can open data/data folder but nothing more. I tried data/data/jansoldat.formular100 and it's not working...

Here is what is in the manifest
`package="jansoldat.formular100"`

Comment: Were you able to find other app packages (in-built)?

Comment: Actually i didn't try that. What do you mean. I think i don't fully understand..