# how can I accesses to data/data from my android device monitor with out rooting my phone?

Tags: android, device

is there a way to do that? My old phone was rooted and I didn't have any problem getting access to data/data but I bought a Nexus 6 and I cant access to data/data from Android Device Monitor.

All the post I have seen are old and said that I need to root my phone.  I know there are a lot of Tutorials on youtube I just dont want to brick my phone, Anyone knows a trusty post so I can root my Nexus 6?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471780/android-adb-retrieve-database-using-run-as

Comment: thanks mate it worked for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @THelper

Accessing the files directly on your phone is difficult, but you may be able to copy them to your computer where you can do anything you want with it. Without rooting you have 2 options:

1.If the application is debuggable you can use the run-as command in adb shell

```
adb shell
run-as com.your.packagename 
cp /data/data/com.your.packagename/
```

2.Alternatively you can use Android's backup function.

```
adb backup -noapk com.your.packagename
```

You will now be prompted to 'unlock your device and confirm the backup operation'. It's best NOT to provide a password, otherwise it becomes more difficult to read the data. Just click on 'backup my data'. The resulting 'backup.ab' file on your computer contains all application data in android backup format. Basically it's a compressed tar file. [This page](https://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2012/06/unpacking-android-backups.html) explains how you can use OpenSSL's zlib command to uncompress it. You can use the `adb restore backup.db` command to restore the backup.