# Not able to access the database file through adb shell... shows permission denied

Tags: android, sqlite, shell, root, adb

I am trying to retrieve the database file from the phone. I am using the cmd and adb shell to do this. After access data/data when i do ls, it shows permission denied. 
I have phone my rooted. USB debugging is on. 
My CMD image is attached. Please guide where i am wrong. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You just run `su` to get root access from the shell.

Comment: Thanks you for you command. it works to access the files but now i cannot copy and paste the database file to my computer.

Comment: You can't "send" files from within ADB, you have to `pull` them

Comment: Yeahh I am doing the same.. like first I write cp databasename /sdcard/ and then pull databasename /sdcard/... I dont know if my commands are wrong but I am doing sam way..

Comment: It is not really clear why you need to copy out the database. You can use a tool like [Stetho](https://facebook.github.io/stetho/) to inspect it

Comment: Now I dont want to spend time on a new tool to handle the database.. I just want it through adb shell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android adb, retrieve database using run-as](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471780/android-adb-retrieve-database-using-run-as)

Answer (score 3):

To list all databases that you have:

```
adb shell run-as com.example.myapp ls /data/data/com.example.myapp/databases/
```

To download them, first, copy them to sdcard and then, pull it:

```
adb shell run-as com.example.myapp cp /data/data/com.example.myapp/databases/DATABASE_NAME /sdcard/

adb pull /sdcard/DATABASE_NAME
```

**NOTE:**

Remember to replace `com.example.myapp` by package name from your app.

Replace `com.example.myapp` by package marked in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest 
    package="com.example.myapp"/>
    ....
</manifest>
```

Comment: Still it shows that com.example.mudasir.login is unknown

Comment: i ran the following commands adb devices and then adb shell run-as com.example.mudasir.login and then ls -1 /data/data/com.example.mudasir.login/databases

Comment: My Manifest file shows this package name.       package="com.example.mudasir.login"

Comment: Also checked "com.example.login". Same Issue..:(

Comment: App is installed on the device up and running. I also wonder why its showing unknow. Is it related to the permission denied..??

Comment: Run this command "adb shell pm list packages" Check if you can find any app with name *mudasir*

Comment: Another point... right command is ( ls -l ) and not ( ls -1 ).. to avoid confusion, remove -l parameter.. run only ls /data/data/com.example.mudasir.login/databases

Comment: su command works to access the internal files of the device and now i can approach to /data/data/com.exmaple.mudasir.login/databases. And if i do ls, i can see my database file. But i issue is i cannot copy and pull the file from device to my computer.

Comment: I was wondering my device don't have any sdcard. Is it considering the internal storage of device as sdcard..? I try to use your given commands but its showing no result. :(

Comment: I spend last 2.5 hours on figuring out this problem. After spending the hours when i put my hands up and by chance i saw my internal storage folder, i saw one database file which was my database. I succeeded randomly and i don't know which solution make it happen. Now again stuck because I don't know which solution worked,

Comment: Please figure out for me because it got stuck into my mind. I know i am doing a little syntax mistake. And in the last it will make me feel like fool..:(

Comment: cp: /sdcard: Permission denied