# ContentValues Insert always return the -1

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, content-values

`db.insert(table_name,null,contentValues);` is always returning `-1` and it is not inserting the values in the databases.

Can you please help me to figure out what I'm doing the wrong?

database_class.java:

```
public class database_class extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String database_name = "signup_db";
    public static final String table_name = "signup";
    public static final String column_1 = "FIRST_NAME";
    public static final String column_2 = "SECOND_NAME";
    public static final String column_3 = "EMAIL";
    public static final String column_4 = "PASSWORD";
    public static final String column_5 = "c_password";

    public database_class(Context context){
        super(context,database_name , null, 1);
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Class called ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table" + table_name + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , FIRST_NAME TEXT , SECOND_NAME TEXT , EMAIL TEXT , PASSWORD TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + table_name);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean insertData(String first_name, String second_name, String email, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(column_1,first_name);
        contentValues.put(column_2,second_name);
        contentValues.put(column_3,email);
        contentValues.put(column_4,password);
        long result = db.insert(table_name,null,contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }
}
```

MainActivity Code:

```
fn = editText1.getText().toString();
ln = editText2.getText().toString();
em = editText3.getText().toString();
pass = editText4.getText().toString();
cpass = editText5.getText().toString();

if (1 == 1) {
    //boolean isInserted =  mydb.insertData(signup_values[0].toString(),signup_values[1].toString(),signup_values[2].toString(),signup_values[3].toString());
    boolean isInserted =  mydb.insertData(fn,ln,em,pass);
    if(isInserted == true) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password Mismatch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I am not an android developer, but given i can't see a way to get the error from the db, i would check that the db you are inserting to is available and open before trying to do your insert.

Comment: Hint: read about java naming conventions. Classes start Uppercase, variables dont have _ in their names. Besides: your names are pretty much horrible! There is no need to save characters; like: what is ln supposed to mean? em? pass? cpass? Use names that say what the thingy they denote **is**. And either use an array for your text fields; or give those appropriate names too. Finally: consider not using static all over the place for your fields. You see - you can make the db name a field that you give to your class in the constructor for example.

Comment: @GhostCat Try to solve the problem, not nitpick the syntax ;) You're wasting your breath

Comment: @cricket_007 Everybody here downvotes bad questions or puts up close requests. That is a convention of this community. Java programmers have conventions too; and I don't see it as a waste of time to tell people about that. And: more than once people came back and said: "oh, i wasn't aware that my code isnt following conventions; i will look into that; thank you". So thanks, but I think I am perfectly able to manage my breath ;-)

Comment: Yeah its true that i am not following the conventions because i am new in java. With the passage of time i will take care of each and every convention. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there's an error while creating your database. This way, `create` table will fail and then, `insert` will also fail (because table was not properly created).

Other parts of your code seems OK...

This line, will produce following string:

```
db.execSQL("create table" + table_name + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , FIRST_NAME TEXT , SECOND_NAME TEXT , EMAIL TEXT , PASSWORD TEXT)");
```

Result:

```
create tablesignup(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , FIRST_NAME TEXT , SECOND_NAME TEXT , EMAIL TEXT , PASSWORD TEXT)
```

This is not valid SQL Command. So, try to add some spaces like:

```
db.execSQL("create table " + table_name + " ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FIRST_NAME TEXT, SECOND_NAME TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT )");
```

**Error 2**

Your `onUpgrade()` also wont work due to same error:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + table_name);
```

Need to add some spaces like:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_name);
```

**Finally**

I tested your code and works fine. Maybe, some error happened before and it would be good to "reinstall" the database.

How you can do:

- Unistall/Install your app
- Update your database version to force `onUpgrade()`. Just do: `super(context, database_name , null, 2);` at `onCreate()`

Comment: You answer was logical and i changed my query with the spaces, but still its returning the -1 value.

Comment: @MudasirRao I updated my answer. Then, I tested result code and it is working fine... If error still persist, unistall/re-install the app to force database creation again

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now its working fine.Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @MudasirRao

Comment: Can you look at this question. If you know any solution.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686196/not-able-to-access-the-database-file-through-adb-shell-shows-permission-denie