# if I update the database by DB Browser, it does not change in my app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I have an SQLite database which I created by using DB Browser, I putted it in assets file and I use SQLiteAssetHelper to access it. Why if I update any record using DB Browser It dose not change in my app ?!
Also If I execute insert query in my app, the new record does not appear in DB Browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with 3 different databases:

1. The database you create with DB Browser and is stored in a folder in your pc.
2. The database in `assets` folder which is a copy of the database you created with DB Browser
3. The database in your emulator/device that was created the 1st time you ran the app.
    This last database originally was a copy of the database you had in `assets` folder.

When you make changes to the database in case 1, these changes are not reflected to either the database in `assets` folder or in your emulator/device. 
If you want these changes to be made to your emulator/device database, you must:

- Delete the database from `assets` and copy there the changed DB Browser database.
- Uninstall the app from the emulator/device so the database is deleted.
- Run the app again, so the database is recreated in the emulator/device.

When you make changes to the emulator/device and you want to examine the database with DB Browser:

- In Android Studio select *View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer*
- In the *Device File Explorer* window go to **data/data/yourpackagename/databases** folder and right click your database and click **Save as...**. Select the folder where you want the database to be saved and you're done.
  Now you can open the database with DB Browser.

Comment: I deleted the database from assets file, I removed the application from the device, I run the application on my device and it run with the old database, it is still connected with my application

Comment: Did you first copy to the assets folder the new db you created with DB Browser?

Comment: I copied the new database to assets file then I reinstall the application but same problem happened .. the old database is stuck into my app.

Comment: Is there another way to remove the old database instead of uninstall the app?

Comment: Delete it from Device File Explorer

Comment: there is nothing in file Explorer

Comment: I mean `data/data/yourpackagename/databases` folder in **Device File Explorer** in Android Studio. If there is nothing there then the db was deleted.

Comment: I restart my phone and yeees the new database it is work .. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Because `SQLiteAssetHelper` does not copy the database from assets if the database file already exists in the target location.

If it's a development-time change in the database, you can simply uninstall your app to delete the old version of the database.

If it's a change to a released version of your application, you need to implement database versioning and update scripts as mentioned in the [readme](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

> Also If I execute insert query in my app, the new record does not appear in DB Browser.

You're not inserting to the same database but a copy of it. You need to pull the database from your device and check from there. See 
 e.g. [android adb, retrieve database using run-as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471780/android-adb-retrieve-database-using-run-as)