# How to access a database file on android device [Xamarin App with Entity Framework for SQLite]

Tags: android, database, sqlite, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I'm beginner in mobile programming, I'm trying to create a database application in Xamarin Forms, there is an Entity Framework SQLite for easy work with the database. After reading the articles I configuring my app so:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public const string DbFileName = "DailyAppDatabase.db";
        string dbPath = DependencyService.Get<IPath>().GetDatabasePath(DbFileName);

        public App()...
     }
```

In android project I implemented a method that returns the path to the Database:

```
return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), filename);
```

[this metod returns "/data/user/0/com.companyname.daily_app/files/DailyAppDatabase.db"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZCjk.png)

**I think I should search a database file here(I want to get this file and open it in SQLite DB Browser).** 
But I can't use emulators, my virtualization system is not working, I debug my app on physical **unrooted** Android 7.0 device. **How I can do this?**
I've looked at many similar topics like these:

[How to access data/data folder in Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device)

[Retrieve database or any other file from the Internal Storage using run-as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471780/retrieve-database-or-any-other-file-from-the-internal-storage-using-run-as/18472135#18472135)

**but found no answer**, I really need help, I tried following method:

1) [using adb shell command chmod 666 /data/user/0/com.companyname.daily_app/files/DailyAppDatabase.db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huT8j.png)

2)  `adb shell -> run-as com.your.packagename -> cp /data/data/com.your.packagename/`

But result of these commands on my device is permission denied, I tried this method:

```
     string _databasePath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "DailyAppDatabse.db");      
            if (!File.Exists(_databasePath))
                return;
            Stream myInput = new FileStream(_databasePath, FileMode.Open);
            Stream myOutput = Assets.Open("database.db");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int b = buffer.Length;
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.Read(buffer, 0, b)) > 0)
            {
                myOutput.Write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.Flush();
            myOutput.Close();
            myInput.Close();
```

But i Think, this is the wrong way to solve the problem, get an exception "method myOutput.**write** (...) is not supported.
Maybe someone has met this problem and can help, I don't want to get a root access and I like code-first approach in EntityFramework Core for SQLite

Comment: The SQLite.NET library that Xamarin recommends is a very basic ORM that lets you easily store and retrieve objects in the local SQLite database on an Android device.So you can install **sqlite-net-pcl** by Nuget package in your project, there are some article about using it:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm and https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-sqlite-database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it was so difficult for me.
The following algorithm:

1)making backup file (note the attribute android:allowBackup = true in your app manifest)

```
adb backup -f "\location\on\local\drive" -noapk app.package.name
```

2)
unpacking `.ab file to .tar file using abe.jar`

3) there are files and db file in the .tar folder

maybe this will help someone in the future