# VS Code and Flutter - How to open mobile app local db

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, adb

Good morning,

I am developing offline storage for an Android mobile app and I would like to access and open its local database as I always did with web local development, possibly by using some sort of GUI software like DB Browser for SQLite.

I found out where the db file is but it is too much cumbersome exporting it from the Android file system (I tried the ADB backup + decrypt with zlib library way) from a dev point of view. Are there other modern ways?

I'm using Visual Studio Code as code editor.

Comment: If the app is compiled as debuggable build you can use Android Studio file explore to browse and access the app-private files. Internally this works using adb and `runas` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471780/retrieve-database-or-any-other-file-from-the-internal-storage-using-run-as