# How can I install the SQLite executable on an Android device?

Tags: android

I have an root application that reads the SQLite database of WhatsApp. I'm using the `sqlite` binary to execute the SQL query and I read the results into my app.

Now, this all works fine but I've noticed that the SQLite executable seems to be missing on some devices especially the Galaxy S3 GT-I9300. (I can see this through my crash statistics.)

My application also installs the `sqlite3` executable onto the users phone. The SQLite executable needs to be at `/system/xbin/sqlite3` or `/system/bin/sqlite3`. I've bundled the `sqlite3` binary with my application in the `assets` and my application unpacks the assets and copies it over to the correct location. I extracted the `sqlite3` binary from the Android emulator.

Now, I've been seeing errors that read that library file `libncurses.so` is missing. On my phone that file is at `/system/bin/libncurses.so`.

Now, should I also bundle the `libncurses.so` file with my application? Is there anything else I would need to bundle?

If there's a better way of getting `sqlite3` on the device, I'll be glad to hear it.

Comment: What binary do you use? I suppose it is the ["Precompiled binary for Linux"](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)?

Comment: The binary I'm using is from the Android Jelly Bean Emulator. I used `adb`to pull it out of the image.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to escape dependencies just build it yourself with all needed libraries statically linked.

Comment: could you elaborate on how I could do this? I don't have much knowledge of make and gcc but with a little help, I could do it. Thanks.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla I can not help you here much, can only suggest to setup environment to build full android and change it somehow, or go to cyanogen community and ask aid there.

Answer (score 0):

Some searching on SO will result in a plethora of answers:

Here is one: [Why do I get a "sqlite3: not found" error on a rooted Nexus One when I try to open a database using the adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645319/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite3-not-found-error-on-a-rooted-nexus-one-when-i-try-to-op)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing but if you read carefully it doesn't mention anything about shared-library dependencies.