# sqlite3 Segmentation fault in android adb shell

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

When I use sqlite3 in adb shell, the error “Segmentation fault”:

```
shell@android:/data/data/com.yh.web/databases $ ll
ll
-rwxrwxrwx app_106  app_106     12288 2013-09-16 12:33 webview.db
-rwxrwxrwx app_106  app_106     32768 2013-09-16 12:33 webview.db-shm
-rwxrwxrwx app_106  app_106     12608 2013-09-16 12:33 webview.db-wal

shell@android:/data/data/com.yh.web/databases $ sqlite3 webview.db
sqlite3 webview.db
[1] + Stopped (signal)     sqlite3 webview.db

shell@android:/data/data/com.yh.web/databases $

[1] + Segmentation fault   sqlite3 webview.db
```

The sqlite3 is not exist in my phone at first, I pull it from Android virtual machine, and push it to my phone. solve it by [Why do I get a "sqlite3: not found" error on a rooted Nexus One when I try to open a database using the adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645319/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite3-not-found-error-on-a-rooted-nexus-one-when-i-try-to-op)

What's wrong and how can i resolve it, please help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The version of sqlite3 is built based on a particular version of Android. It has to match the version of Android on your phone. You can get more info about sqlite3 in this answer: [Version of SQLite used in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android/4377116#4377116)

**Edit:**

Assuming you have root access, you can look for an sqlite binary matching your version of Android from the [Google Factory images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images). If that doesn't work, you can do something similar with a matching version of CyanogenMod and extracting the `sqlite` binary from it. I think Android 4.0.4 matches CM 9.1. You can take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyanogenMod#Version_history . I think this should be enough to get you started. I don't guarantee that the `sqlite` binary will work with your phone, though.

Comment: Yes, I find my Android version is 4.0.4 and match SQLite 3.7.4, the link is [SQLite3.7.4](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_7_4), but the [download page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) has not sign about android, where can I download the sqlite3 file while can run on my phone? Thanks!