# sh: /system/bin/sqlite3: not executable: magic 7F45

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

I followed link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645319/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite3-not-found-error-on-a-rooted-nexus-one-when-i-try-to-op/5022363#5022363) to set up sqlite3 to run from adb to read my application database. but getting

sh: /system/bin/sqlite3: not executable: magic 7F45

in cmd. what is the problem? how can I fix it?

Comment: so any way? that could be helpful for me to get rid of it.

Comment: you got the wrong version of the binary. you need to find the correct version

Comment: you were right @AlexP.