# Android Studio - How Can I Make an AVD With ARM Instead of HAXM?

Tags: android, arm, haxm, amd-processor

I'm new to Android Studio. My computer doesn't support HAXM so it won't let me install that to use for virtualization. In some similar questions on this website people mention setting up a virtual device with an ARM instead of HAXM. How can I do this?

In the AVD manager all of the premade hardware profiles use HAXM, and when I click "New Hardware Profile" I don't see any option to use ARM. I looked in the SDK Manager and for API 22 I have installed "ARM EABI v7a System Image" and "Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image", are those what I need?

How can I create a custom virtual phone with ARM, or is there a way I can use one of the preexisting hardware devices with ARM instead of HAXM?

Answer (score 126):

I figured it out and I'll answer it here in case anybody else finds this question.

1. Go to Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager
2. Click "Create Virtual Device"
3. Select which device you want to use from the list (i.e Nexus 5) and click "Next".
4. Here you're given a list of android release versions. Look at the ABI column. "Armeabi-v7a" ABI is what to look for, for whichever API Level you want.
5. Hit "Next" and modify name/size if you want, click "Finish" when done.

Comment: If you don't see the "arm" options, switch tab to "Other Images" between steps 3 and 4.

Comment: i wish one could provide his own custom image (when building AOSP)

Comment: ALL of the images in all of the tabs, including the ARM images, say "Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM).

Comment: I have followed the instructions and the emulator appears but suddenly crushes! this is the crush message: `Crash reason:  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_WRITE
Crash address: 0x0
Assertion: Unknown assertion type 0x00000000
Process uptime: not available` any help !!!

Comment: Sadly, all the ARM emulators are very old. The newest I can get is an API 25 emulator.

Answer (score 43):

If you didn't see the ARM option as [user2636417 wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405740/android-studio-how-can-i-make-an-avd-with-arm-instead-of-haxm#30407459), just click on "Other Images" tab and download the desired ARM option.

[image: How to add a new ARM image]

Comment: I don't see those tabs on my version of Android Studio. 3.1.2

Comment: As I'm writing this the most recent Android API level is 28 (Android 9.0) but the newest ARM ABIs on the list are only API level 25 (Android 7.1.1). Is Google not providing these anymore?

Comment: No. @apaatsio google are not providing ARM emulator builds. But I see that the latest preview build Android 11 have now got ARM emulators https://www.electronicsweekly.com/news/google-smooths-android-path-emulated-arm-app-support-2020-03/ . hope that helps.