# Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD Your CPU does not support VT-x

Tags: android-studio

I know there are a lot of similar questions out there, and I am new to Android world. I get the following errors as I try to run app (Shift + F10)

Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.

Your CPU does not support VT-x.

Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.

Here are some of your options:

1. User a physical device for testing
2. Develop on a windows/osx computer with an intel processor that supports VT-x and NX
3. Develop on a linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
4. Use an Android Virtual Device Based on an ARM system image
   (This is 10x slower that hardware accelerated virtualization)

[image: Android Studio Error]

When I do dxdiag on this computer(windows 10) I get the following. Its long but the system information is as below. I am not able to determine if my PC can be used to develop android application. Can someone please help me? Is virtualization required to develop android apps?

In [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/your-cpu-does-not-support-vtx-im-getting-this-error-while-running-my-project-in-android-studio-2-please-help) it is suggested that we have to enable VT-x in bios, but I dont see anything of that sort in my bios. Is there a way out of my predicament?

---

### System Information

```
  Time of this report: 12/29/2016, 15:24:38
         Machine name: DESKTOP-DTQ75J3
           Machine Id: {8D78413A-33B7-4359-BB61-8841CC747D2C}
     Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit (10.0, Build 14393) (14393.rs1_release_inmarket.161208-2252)
             Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
  System Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
         System Model: G41M-Combo
                 BIOS: Award Modular BIOS v6.00PG
            Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7400  @ 2.80GHz (2 CPUs), ~2.8GHz
               Memory: 4096MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 4060MB RAM
            Page File: 4199MB used, 2548MB available
          Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
   System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
      DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
             Miracast: Not Available
```

Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.14393.0000 64bit Unicode

Answer (score 11):

Make an AVD With ARM Instead of HAXM -

1. Go to Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager
2. Click "Create Virtual Device"
3. Select which device you want to use from the list (i.e Nexus 5) and click "Next".
4. Here you're given a list of android release versions. Look at the ABI column. "Armeabi-v7a" ABI is what to look for, for whichever API Level you want.
5. Hit "Next" and modify name/size if you want, click "Finish" when done.

Courtesy: [user2636417's answer to "Android Studio - How Can I Make an AVD With ARM Instead of HAXM?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30407459/9404410)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html), to run an emulator the development system's CPU should support one of the following virtualization extensions technologies:

- Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x, vmx)
- AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) -- only supported for Linux

Your CPU is [Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E7400](https://ark.intel.com/products/36500/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7400-3M-Cache-2_80-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB), which according to the manufacturer **may or may not** support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). For example, SLGW3 has VT-x, while the SLB9Y and SLGQ8 do not. Looks like your particular CPU doesn't have VT-x, hence the error.

The workaround is to use an alternative Android Emulator, e.g. [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).