# Cannot install an Android emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have an `<asus tuf gaming fx505dt-bq051t amd ryzen 5-3550h / 8gb / 512gb ssd / geforce gtx 1650 4gb / full hd>`. I have enabled SVM mode, I have downloaded Android Studio. However I cannot Run an android emulator. I get an error message, when i try to install an emulator, that the CPU does not support VT-x(even though it does).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can support but are you sure about that "Enabled". Because i faced problem something like that and i remember the solution is in the Bios menu. In bios menu i changed the "intel virtualization technology" to enable. Maybe it can help you: https://www.intel.com.tr/content/www/tr/tr/support/articles/000007139/server-products.html

or changing the arch of device can be the solution like that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49013111/6307897

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable virtualization in the BIOS, then try installing the android emulator; if when you try to run the emulator it gives you privilege problems, and you're on linux, run this command from the terminal:

```
sudo chown username /dev/kvm
```