# Add ARM system image to Android Studio AVD manager

Tags: android, android-studio, arm, virtualization, android-virtual-device

I have a 64 bit OS, unfortunately my CPU is not supporting VT-x (as it is an Intel CPU it is not supporting also [SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#AMD_virtualization_.28AMD-V.29)).

It means that normal system image is not usable in Android Studio. Help in Android Studio mentions that one may use

> Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image

Armeabi-v7a from "other images" is mentioned in [Android Studio - How Can I Make an AVD With ARM Instead of HAXM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405740/android-studio-how-can-i-make-an-avd-with-arm-instead-of-haxm) as one that should work, unfortunately also system images with "Armeabi-v7a" ABI are listed as requiring VT-x

[image]

How one may add ARM system image to this list?

versions: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit, Android Studio 2.3.3, Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T6600  @ 2.20GHz CPU (according to `/proc/cpuinfo`)

Comment: Pick a platform you already have (such as API 15) and hit Next.  Or, download one you want and hit Next.  Then proceed through the wizard.

Comment: @nasch Every single image has grayed out "next" button.

Comment: If you select IceCreamSandwich, is there red text on the right hand side indicating why you cannot proceed?

Comment: @nasch Yes - http://i.imgur.com/k8g08it.png

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, I thought any processor would support ARM system images.  I can't run x86 images because my processor doesn't support HAXM (or I couldn't get it to install, I don't remember) but ARM works fine.  You could try running a Genymotion emulator instead.

Comment: I have the same problem. All images, including the ARM images, require  VT-x.