# Unable to run react native application in emulator in amd based pc?

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to **run react native** in an emulator in my **AMD based Pc**. I get this error saying:

> Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
>
> Failed to install on any devices.

I have shown this error in the below image:
[image]

I am following the [official document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

> In the official document, click the tab called **"Building Projects with
> Native Code"**. For **Development OS : Windows** and **Target OS :
> Android**.

Note: Due to my AMD processor I have not installed **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator HAXM**, see below image:

[image]

So as a work around for AMD processor I have followed [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405740/android-studio-how-can-i-make-an-avd-with-arm-instead-of-haxm) stackoverflow answer, to install ABI called **arm64-v80** android 7.0 Nougat when creating a Virtual Device in Android studio. My virtual device is ready and also running now, see below image:

[image]

I can correctly start my emulator as shown below image:

[image]

MY Installed SDK platforms are:

[image]

My SDK tools are show below:

[image]

I don't know what is wrong? Please help???

Comment: can you show your apps' build.gradle file that which api you are targeting! and @Florin Dobre's answer is quite helpful i can see!

Comment: can you add build.gradle code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `react-native run-android` command is trying to run the app on an API 24 simulator and you started an API 25 one.

Check all the API 24 dependencies and start the API 24 emulator. It should work.

Here is a configuration that works in my case:

[image]

[image]

Additional notes:

- From your pictures the emulator is not started yet. Check that simulator is really started yet.
- Make sure you use Android Studio 3.1.4 and not 3.2.0 if you have RN 0.57.
- Try to sync gradle and run the project from Android studio, it might work or give you more error info
- Try to Add the API 24 deps and to start an API 25 simulator (From what I know AVD might require some deps from and older API level.

Answer (score 2):

On pc, you should run x86 based emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart your ADB server. You need to run 2 separate commands:

`adb kill-server` - to kill the ADB server.

and

`adb start-server` - to start the server again.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I tried restarting my android emulator and pc too but it is of no use.