# Error launching AVD in latest Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I recently upgrade to the latest android studio, although i had not use it in a long time. My code build up and sync successful but I get the error below each time I tried to the app in an emulator. **pls note, I use Window 10 on AMD based system**

`Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration`

I had installed and enable "Intel HAXM". I have browsed through a few similar question but none provides a solution.

[image]

Please not this question is a different scenario to what you have the question [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration):

- No information about Intel HAXM status nor CPU acceleration status
- The version of Android Studio is way different
- possible difference in the way SDK Manager was back in 2015 and now

Comment: go to SDK manager and check for update

Comment: Update intel HAXM

Comment: If you are on Windows 10: Have you enabled the security function "core isolation"? If yes disable it otherwise the visualization function of your CPU is not available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

Comment: You need to see if Virtualization is enabled or disabled on BIOS Settings. If it is disabled then you need to enable it.

Comment: Thanks guys! not sure about the virtualization thing but will check now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you posted is just a workaround.

As a i solution (i have the same AMD platform - 2700X my cpu), you need to enable from BIOS - your virtualisation technology (i have a Aorus motherboard and its called SMT), and then from the OS - Turn Windows Features ON or OFF - install [image: hypervisorPlatform]

After this option is installed, you should be able to run the AVD with proper emulation. I already uninstalled HAXM and had no issues without it.

Also, i did not install any Hyper-V

[image: hyperVDisplay]

**PS:
As of 26 Oct 2019, Google added support for AMD CPU as per their blog: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/10/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for.html 
You need to make sure you disable the previous settings provided by me up above, and follow their guide.**

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by Alex8752 on the post [Android Studio - How Can I Make an AVD With ARM Instead of HAXM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405740/android-studio-how-can-i-make-an-avd-with-arm-instead-of-haxm) as guideline to resolve the above issue.

Basically since I use AMD system, I downloaded and installed arm* image from "Other Image" within System Image (*I will recommend **armeabi-v7a** for x86-64 based systems*). Thanks to everyone.