# How do I change the CPU/ABI of an Android Virtual device?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.3

I have three Android Virtual Devices.  For all of them, the CPU/ABI field is set to x86.

I want to change it to some of the ARM stuff, but I couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way you can do this is by creating another AVD with ARM instruction set.

Changing the instruction set of an existing virtual device is like changing the instruction set of an actual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The emulators are running on an x86 device, and only run x86 code.  They don't simulate the chipset, so they can't run ARM code.  Attempting to do so would make them 10x or more slower.

Comment: Do you mean we cannot have an ARM based AVD or if we have them they would be slower?

Comment: You cn't have an ARM based AVD.  It would be a completely different type of tech than the Android emulator uses, it would need to simulate the chipset.  Even if you were to try to do this (which is more or less what old video game emulators do), it would be painfully slow.  Which is why the emulator doesn't do that, and runs only x86 code.

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405740/android-studio-how-can-i-make-an-avd-with-arm-instead-of-haxm

I myself have created an ARM based AVD.