# Getting Android Studio AVD To Work With Mac Mini M1

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm having trouble getting my emulator to work on my m1 mac. Currently, I am waiting on my physical android phone to arrive so I have to use an emulator for the moment. I have looked at the official google repo (https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview) for the m1 preview and I noticed it said "Support for downloading the M1-based emulator was added to SDK Manager, so it's not necessary to go to the Github releases page to download a standalone .app anymore. In AVD Manager go to the Other Images tab as by default it doesn't show the ARM64 images." However, I can't seem to find which SDK to download in the SDK manager as every time I attempt to cold boot a virtual device it simply returns the error "Could Not Start AVD".
Sorry if this has been asked before. Couldn't seem to find any posts about it.

Answer (score 0):

So it took some time but I figured it out. In the updated Android Studio you have to create a new virtual device for ARM based machines. Once you select your new device and you get to what android release you would like to run, hit the "other" column. Now you have a list of some of the ARM based Virtual Devices.
Here is a link to a post I found that helped:
[Android Studio - How Can I Make an AVD With ARM Instead of HAXM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405740/android-studio-how-can-i-make-an-avd-with-arm-instead-of-haxm)

Comment: Install Android Studio/Emulator on macOS with new ARM CPU M1
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BIPAG-Cn6Y

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Dolphin, Virtual Device Manager, now includes arm64a-v8a for Tiramisu API level 33, which works well for M1 mac.