# Why does getWritableDatabase crashes on some devices? (sqlite3_open_v2 ... Failed)

Tags: android, database, crash, getwritabledatabase, forceclose

My application uses a database and works pretty well on all Android devices.

Recently some users pointed that it crashes on HTC Tattoo. I decided to give a try and got one in loan.

So, the error come when I call: this.getWritableDatabase();

```
09-27 18:26:22.292: ERROR/Database(1537): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.xxx.xxx/databases/radars.db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
09-27 18:26:22.292: WARN/System.err(1537): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
```

And I have checked, the Database is in the device:

[image]

I really cannot understand what happens....

Thank a lot for your help!

**EDIT:**

As noticed by LAS_VEGAS

```
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.xxx.xxx/databases/radars.db
```

Gives this result:

```
sqlite3: not found
```

Seem that the HTC Tattoo has serious SQL issues:

> adb shell
>    # cd /system/xbin
>    # ls | grep sqlite3
>
> //Nothing//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird. I think this could happen when you try to access database file from multiple threads simultaneously. Could it be the case?

Also for testing purposes did you try `getReadableDatabase()`, maybe it gives a clue...

**EDIT:**
Can you access from remote shell?:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite

**EDIT2:**
So it seems that HTC tattoo has no sqlite3.

Comment: You are close to something: # sqlite3 /data/data/com.profete162.WebcamWallonnes/databases/radars.db
sqlite3: not found
But, I have the file (see screenshot in my question)

Comment: Seem related to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645319/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite3-not-found-error-on-a-rooted-nexus-one-when-i-try-to-ope

Comment: I think you should get permission denied, like it says here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645122/why-does-sqlite3-command-using-the-android-adb-shell-return-permission-denied, so there is something wrong with sqlite. you may need to root the device and check.

Comment: I think we are talking about 2 different issues. On your link, sqlite3: permission denied  and in my case: sqlite3: not found.. So, according to this post, SQL is simply not installed on a Tattoo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645319/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite3-not-found-error-on-a-rooted-nexus-one-when-i-try-to-ope

Comment: Actually we are talking about the same thing. The fact that you get "not found"  instead of "permission denied" shows that sqlite3 might not be there at all.

Comment: We agree, the HTC tattoo has no sqlite3. Period. Edit your answer, so I can accept it ;-)